# Correct approach for checking memory allocations in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, ios, memory-management

I'm wondering what would be the correct approach after executing a command that allocates memory in Objective C (I'm mainly referring to iOS apps).
My dilemma comes from the fact that checking for the success of failure of a memory allocation operation adds lots of lines of code, while wondering whether this is at all useful.
Moreover, sometimes memory allocations are obvious, such as using 'alloc', but sometimes they are taking place behind the scenes. And even if we check each and every allocation - when we find it failed - there isn't much we could actually do. So maybe the correct approach is to just let it fail and have the app crash?
Take a look at this code:

```
// Explicit memory allocation
NSArray a1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:someObj, nil];
if (!a1) {
  // Should we make this check at all? Is there really what to do?
}

// Implicit memory allocation
NSArray a2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:someObj, nil];
if (!a2) {
  // should we make this check at all? Is there really what to do?
}
```

What in your opinion would be the correct approach? Check or not check for allocation failures? iOS developers out there - how have you handled it in your apps?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

With the power you have in an Iphone/smartphone, the time it takes to compute a few test is ridiculous to be thinking "is it really worth checking", it is always good test and catch any failures in your code/allocations. (if you don't it sounds more like your lazy to add a few extra lines in your code.

Also "letting the app crash" gives a REALLY poor impression of your application, the user see the app close for no reason and thinks its a poor quality software.
You should always add your tests and if you can't do anything about the error then at least you should display a message before the app closes (makes the user less frustrated).

there a several options when tracking memory allocations, like catching exception. testing if the pointer returned is nil, checking the size of the list etc.

you should think of ways to let your application run in the case the allocation fails:

- if it is jsut a view of your interface, display a message saying fail to load the particular view ...
- if it is the main and only view, close the application gracefully with a message

...

I don't know what application you are working on but if you are short on memory, you should consider creating a system to allocate a deallocated memory as your progressing in your app, so that you always have the maximum memory available. it might be slightly slower than keeping everything cached but you app quality will improve if you suppress any force close.

Comment: Good luck with showing messages if you couldn't allocate memory for a 20 byte object :-)

Comment: Exactly... if you fail to allocate a simple array, you won't be able to show a message... I think that the reality is that people "think" that they've covered themselves from memory allocation problems, but they never actually test these situations (as you can't really simulate a memory allocation failure in every second line of your code. Therefore in practice if that happens - maybe you covered the first failure but you will end up failing a few lines further. It somehow really looks like we're doing a lot of work around it, checking for these failures, when in fact it's useless.

Comment: My point being you should try and handle the maximum of cases rather than adopt the attitude "Since it failed I'll just let it crash"

Comment: Yes, obviously I totally agree that the "just let it crash" approach is not the ideal way. But I was actually looking for a better way to do it rather than handle it on the micro level, for every allocation. For example - attach a general exception handler to catch all failures, or something alike. In fact, in my applications I do use a general handler, but in parallel I check each and every allocation. Somehow it doesn't seem to be the ideal way. Also - Objective-C supports try/catch, but I noticed it is rarely used for some reason. Something just doesn't fall into place with this issue.

Comment: If allocations are failing, "just let it crash" is the only recourse.  There is no guarantee that any of the underlying system state is in anyway consistent enough to report anything useful to the user.

Answer (score 11):

**Fantasy:** Every memory allocation would be checked and any failure would be reported to the user in a friendly fashion, the app would shut down cleanly, a bug report would be sent, you could fix it and the next version would be perfect [in that one case].

**Reality:** By the time something as trivial as `arrayWithObjects:` fails, your app was dead long, long, ago.   There is no recovery in this case.   It is quite likely that the frameworks have already failed an allocation and have already corrupted your app's state.

Furthermore, once something as basic as `arrayWithObjects:` has failed, you aren't going to be able to tell the user anyway.  There is no way that you are going to be able to reliably put a dialog on screen without further allocations.

However, the failure happened much further before your app failed an allocation.  Namely, your app should have received a memory warning and should have responded by (a) persisting state so no customer data is lost and (b) freeing up as much memory as possible to avoid catastrophic failure.

Still, a memory warning is the last viable line of defense in the war on memory usage.

Your first assault on memory reduction is in the design and development process.  You should consider memory use from the start of the application development process and you *must* optimize for memory use as you polish your application for publication.   Use the Allocations Instrument (see this [Heapshot analysis write-up](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) I did a bit ago -- it is highly applicable) and justify the existence of every major consumer of memory.

Comment: Fully agree we need to strive to reduce memory consumption. I've also used Instruments for that purpose. Still I keep wondering whether checking for a memory failure in each and every line is the way to code. In your apps - are you checking for a mem failure after every small memory operation?

Comment: Nope;  the only time I check for `nil` or `NULL` returns on allocations is when there is some kind of logic related to the allocation of the memory (i.e. `newWithSomethingThatMightBeInvalid:`) might purposefully return `NULL/nil`.   Trying to do so on, say, `malloc()` or the equivalent is utterly pointless.

Answer (score 2):

iPhone apps should register for UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification notifications. iOS will send these when available memory gets low. Google iphoneappprogrammingguide.pdf (dated 10/12/2011) for more information.

That said, one general approach to the problem I've seen is to reserve a block of memory at app startup as a "cushion". In your code put in a test after each allocation. If an allocation fails, release the cushion so you have enough memory to display an error message and exit. The size of the cushion has to be large enough to accommodate allowing your hobbled app to shutdown nicely. You could determine the size of the cushion by using a memory stress tester.

This is really a tricky problem because it happens so rarely (for well-designed programs). In the PC/mini/mainframe world virtual memory virtually eliminates the problem in but the most pathological programs. In limited memory systems (like smartphones), stress testing your app with a heap monitor tool should give you a good indication of its max memory usage. You could code a high water mark wrapper routine for alloc that does the same thing.

Comment: Many of the responses to this question, including my own above, say to exit gracefully. Well, as far as I know, there's no API to exit an iOS app. The official procedure is to respond to the low memory warning by overriding the designated method in the app delegate or UIViewController or register for the notification. (See Apple's iPhone Programming Guide mentioned above.) At that point you free up as much allocated memory as you can and/or alert the user. This feels heretical to say, but you don't really need to test after every allocation as long as you respond to the low memory warning.

Answer (score 0):

Check them, assert in debug (so you know where/why failures exist), and push the error to the client (in most cases). The client will typically have more context - do they retry with a smaller request? fail somehow? disable a feature? Display an alert to the user, etc, etc. The examples you have provided are not the end of the world, and you can gracefully recover from many - furthermore, you need to (or *ought* to) know when and where your programs fail.

Comment: This is true in a place where you know you're about to allocate a big chunk of memory. In that case you better check the result, and probably do something else if you can. But I was referring to all those small allocations that happen in every second line of your code. A failure there would mean that you will also fail trying to display a message to the user. Please see also my answer to Jason below.

Comment: 1) your original question was not limited to small allocations 2) chances are, you're not going to disassemble every call to determine what is a 'small allocation' - there's a lot that happens behind the scenes 3) what you believe/write is an nomem condition will fail more often for other reasons, such as an invalid argument/context. if you're not going to do a simple null check before use... i would definitely not expect you to write/maintain all these conditions (especially when you don't have the sources). 4) graceful recovery is an option, and you should know/correct your app's failures.

Comment: 5) failure also means you can localize the problem in log message, or in the crash report.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand you, and perhaps my original question was somewhat unclear. If I ask you personally - are you checking for null after each and every operation that may return null due to a memory problem (such as the examples I've originally given)? If you do , do you feel this is the right approach?

Comment: do i check? yes, in the majority of cases (included the examples you've given). i don't have 100% coverage, but most points are checked -- particularly where code is reused. error testing/handling is typically more than half the function/method body in SLOC, but this degree of correctness keeps the defect count low. positives typically catch issues other than out of memory issues. out of memory occurrences are very rare. do i think it's the right approach? yes, i want to know where and why the program fails - most defects can be resolved.

Comment: How about an example?